# Laptop fan does not work after suspend

Tags: suspend, fan

My laptop is acre swift 3 i7 10th gen. So I have install latest version of Ubuntu and I use this laptop for programming only. **When after the laptop suspend manually or automatically the fan of the laptop doesn't work**. when i restart the laptop again the fan is working.

What is the reason for this? How can I over come this problem?

Comment: Why are you thinking this is a problem? Does the laptop overheat? And what is "latest version of Ubuntu"?

Comment: Power Management handles Suspend/Hibernate/Resume, and will let you tickle your device going down and coming up.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement